# What do I want to do when upgrading jQuery from 1.4.x to 1.6.x

Tags: jquery

Currently I use 1.4.4 in my sites, and considering upgrading to the latest (1.6.4).  In your experience, is there any reason why I shouldn't just replace the jquery file (I host it in my server).  What things should I be careful of?

Comment: Plugins, gotcha. But is there anything that screams 'WAIT!' in all the versions from 1.4.4 and 1.6.4 that definitely needs to be verified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this blog that covers all the important points...

http://davidtong.me/upgrading-jquery-from-1-4-x-to-1-6-1

Paraphrased tips:

- You should check every use of `.attr()`... There are many that should now be `.prop()`
- JSON Parsing is MUCH MORE strict in 1.5+
- New AJAX module with lots of improvements you can take advantage of.

This should apply for all 1.4.x -> 1.6.x releases.

You might also want to take a look at the [1.7 release candidate notes](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/10/24/jquery-1-7-rc1-released/) as that is soon approaching as well...

Comment: Looks like the major problems were about the change of attr to prop in 1.6 but these were later made more backwards compatible in 1.6.1. The other major change was about ajax but that didn't affect me, so I just replaced the jquery file, tested and didn't have to change anything (as far as I could test).  Still not entirely sure what the difference between attr and prop is, for example, is an input's 'autocomplete' an attr or a prop?

Answer (score 1):

The thing that can break is plugins. You should:

- check the plugin official compatibility notes
- carefully test each feature that relies on plugins

Answer (score 1):

have a look through the release notes and look at the breaking changes.   see if any of those will affect your code, and go from there.

personally, i'm still using 1.4.2 on one of my projects b/c there was some changes to the way ajax requests / data was handled (i don't remember exactly what) and it completely broke a lot of my model binding and such.

Comment: yes, I was reading the release notes but, it's like 15 versions, was wondering if anybody had experience (like you) in something that broke for them that I should look for. So ajax, noted.

Comment: the ajax stuff also depends on what your using on the back end, i think php was ok with it, but asp.net mvc 2's model binder really didn't like it.

Answer (score 1):

There are some semantical fixes in jQuery 1.6.

For example, certain things like `defaultValue` and `checked` have always been considered to be "properties", but in the past, jQuery has accessed them as if they were "attributes".  jQuery 1.6 now correctly accesses "properties" with `prop` rather than `attr`.

Therefore, you *may* need to update lines of code that use `attr()` and `removeAttr()`, as appropriate, to `prop()` and `removeProp()`.

Otherwise, check the website of each plugin to see if there are updates and apply them.  Then update jQuery and see what happens.  You can always put it back the way it was.

Answer (score 0):

You should check any plugins for compatibility and upgrade those and thoroughly test everything after upgrading.  Otherwise it should be fairly painless.